# Linux: Start a cron job inside another cron job

Tags: linux, cron, cron-task

I am dealing with a workflow where I need to start three processes. I have the first process which is to be scheduled at the beginning of every hour and the rest two at 45th minute of every hour and the 52nd minute of every hour.

But Instead of making the client schedule two different jobs on their server what I would rather want is to have just one job configured to run in the beginning of every hour which does a bunch of stuff and then starts these cron jobs at their respective times. i.e. 45th minute and 52nd minute of the hour.

Is there any way to do this.

I don't have any experience with shell scripting and always schedule cron jobs manually on cron-tab.

Thanks!

Comment: You're spec isn't very clear, really.  You're speaking of two jobs initially, and then it's three jobs, one of which "does stuff at the hour" and then starts two other jobs?  And what's wrong w/ scheduling two or three jobs?  There's really no point in re-inventing scheduling ...

Comment: @tink Check the edit. I think you are right. I am just getting paranoid. I will probably schedule all these jobs separately. Thanks!